# Replace data in cells based on content of another cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, replace

I'm not overly familiar with VBA and I am struggling a little to write a macro that can look at entire ranges.   I want to automate a way to replace cells in a single worksheet that have Null in a specific column.

I've had some limited success with IF Then Else statements using specific cell values but cannot figure out using cell ranges.
 i.e.

```
IF Range("B1").Value = "Null" And Range("A1").Value = ("*book") Then Range("C1").Value = ("book")
```

Here is an example of the data set:

[image: Sample data set]

In Column A are types of books, tables and chair. Each item has the word Book, Table or Chair in the description, Column B should have a category description but some cell say Null.  What I am trying to do is if the value in column B says "Null" then enter a description of either Book,Table or Chair into Column C based on the value in Column A.  If the value in Column B is not Null then do nothing.   This is just an example, the real data set has around 25,000 rows.

Comment: `Range("A1").Value like "*book"`

Comment: look into a for/next loop or a do loop to read and change each row in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very rough example of code. There are many ways to approach this.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' get the row number of the last row with data in column A
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' Start in row 2
For i = 2 To lRow
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "Null" And Range("A" & i).Value Like "*book" Then
        Range("C" & i).Value = ("book")
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Edit: adjusted code to dynamically determine the last row with data.

Comment: Thanks, that works!  the only issue is that the row counts will vary but will always be over 20,000 rows. is there any way to dynamically adjust that value?